# Can i clone an existing iframe and place it in another div?

Tags: jquery

If I am trying to do `$($('#iframeid').clone()).appendTo('#SomeDiv')` then once again an http request is sent and the newly appended iframe is now containing a fresh page rather the page with existing data. Any solution? I want to copy the iframe into a specific div structure so that jquery splitter plugin can understand that .

Comment: Is the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: With "ajax request", do you mean the `src` attribute of the iframe? You probably don't want to clone the iframe itself, but it's content, that however isn't easy. You need to give some more details.

Comment: Ya I want to clone the content of the Iframe. The iframe is in the same domain. Is there any way to clone the content of the iframe? because whenever I am trying to append and existing iframe into div its content is getting lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, the content inside the `iframe` doesn't get included when the browsers builds the DOM. So, `clone` just clones the `iframe` with its attributes but without the content inside. It is like copy-pasting the `<iframe src="SOMEURL">`. So, it sends yet another `HTTP` request for the requested resource.

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
$('#iframeid').clone().appendTo('#SomeDiv')
```

You can also use

```
$('#iframeid').clone().insertAfter('#SomeDiv')
```

or

```
$('#iframeid').clone().insertBefore('#SomeDiv')
```